# Open sets in the topology of weak convergence

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, probability-theory, self-learning

I do have various questions regarding the topic of probability measures on polish spaces in general, thus I am trying to divide them in “small” subquestions. Hence, this is my first question on this issue.

**Notation:**

- $\Omega$ is a Polish space;
- $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$;
- $\Delta (\Omega)$ is the set of probability measures on $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.

Quite often I read that  $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ is endowed with the **topology of weak convergence**,
where the topology of weak convergence states that for every real function $f$ bounded, continuous on $\Omega$, 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f d\mu_n = \int f d\mu.$$

Here there are my basic questions:

- *How does the topology of weak convergence* creates *open sets in $\Delta (\Omega)$?*
- *How do those open sets look like?*

As always, any feedback regarding anything will be more than welcome.

Thank you for your time.

PS: Maybe the question looks naive, but I am trying to see why, if $\Omega$ is Polish, then $\Delta (\Omega)$ endowed with the topology of weak convergence is Polish as well (of course, any feedback regarding this issue is welcome as well!). Thus I would like to see how the topology of weak convergence actuallys ***works***.

Comment: PPS: I am wondering about the title. I am not sure it is completely correct, but I do not think it is misleading.

Comment: It's the minimal topology on $\Delta(\Omega)$ that makes the all functions $I(f): \Delta(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, where $f$ is bounded continuous on $\Omega$, and $I(f)$ maps a measure $\mu$ to $\int f d\mu$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Thanks a lot. Actually I know this part of definition. My problem is in actually ***seeing*** how the open sets in $\Delta (\Omega)$ look like. I cannot make the connection between what you write and this issue [moreover, as I wrote in the PS, I have an higher goal behind the question]

Comment: https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf gives an explicit metric for this topology. They look like nice notes on the subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I guess you are referring to the Prokhorov metric. Thus, correct me if I am wrong, the idea is that the **topology of weak convergence** can be induced by a metric, namely the **Prokhorov metric**, _i.e._ the topological space $( \Delta (\Omega) , w^* )$, where $w^*$ denotes the topology of weak convergence (*denoted in this way, because it should be equivalent to the weak-star topology on the same space*), is nothing more than the metric space $( \Delta (\Omega) , d_P )$, where $d_P$ denotes the Prokhorov metric. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is shown in those notes that they define the same topology. The completeness is not shown, I think, except for the compact case (when $\Delta(\Omega)$ is also compact).

Comment: Why is it the weak star topology? $\Delta(\Omega)$ is not a topological vector space, so weak star has no meaning here. That is only defined for topologies on dual topological vector spaces, AFAIK.

Comment: I knew I was going to fail on the weak-start point. I have a question on this issue (i.e. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109143/weak-topologies-and-weak-convergence-looking-for-feedbacks ) and I still cannot see it properly. However, I thought, with some weak-star corroboration to my absolutely weak intuition coming from the answers to that question, that $ \langle \Omega, \Delta (\Omega) \rangle$ is indeed a dual pair, and hence the weak-star topology (that in this case should look like the topology of weak convergence) applies.

Comment: @Kolmin: Formally it is not quite a dual pair. As Henno already mentioned what is missing is that the probability measures don't form a vector space. So for this question as you rightly did one is interested in topological issues only.

Comment: @Kolmin: Besides, good that you split it up. So you know how the open sets look like formally but no idea how to deal with them especially how to prove that it is indeed a polish space. I think, or better I guess, it is fair enough to make this the central point here: Do the probability measures form a Polish space?